# How to insert sql date as 04/05/2017 am trying with this

Tags: java, oracle, date

```
java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("dob"));
System.out.println(date);  
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("insert into lol values(?,?)");
ps.setString(1, name);
ps.setDate(2, sqlDate);
```

But output is `05-MAY-17` this, i want store `04-05-2017` in oracle db. Can any one help me

Comment: A date is a date, you are talking about formatting a date as a string representation . You store a date as is, it has no specific format.

Comment: Do not confuse how something is displayed with how something is stored. You can easily change how the date is displayed by formatting it once its retrieved from the database.

Comment: thank you @ Burhan Khalid for reply i will check how to convert it after retrieving.

Comment: @bharathvarma Why are you using `date.getTime()`? Why don't you try `ps.setDate(date)`?

Comment: @user75ponic, because `preparedStatement.setDate()` doesn't accept a `java.util.Date` argument, it needs a `java.sql.Date`. The conversion happens through `getTime()`.

Answer (score -1):

Make the varchar column in db . Store it as a String .

When you want to do some operation at Application Level , convert the string into date . 
For that you can use SimpleDateFormat

Comment: @Vikrant - Bad advice. Why would you want to store date as string? Just for displaying purpose? Bharath - Let it be stored as date and change the format while displaying.

Comment: It’s an option, but it will usually not be what you want. Better store as the correct type (date) and format when it needs to be displayed.

Comment: @Utsav . I feel the best way to do is store in milliseconds , retrieve the value and convert into any data format you want . So you have a loose coupling in that casing . Considering internalization  data format changes from region to region .    Storing date in any format is not recommended unless and until you are really sure that you are gonna use the same format every time

Comment: @Vikrant With all due respect, storing date values other than date data types is not a good design of database tables.

Comment: @vikrant can you please see this, how to run an java .exe file when clicked on html button , i searched a lot but did not get answer .